# How is a function made inherently asynchronous in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have been trying to understand how asynchronous JavaScript works. From what I understand, the language is by-default synchronous and single-threaded.

**Synchronous** in the sense that during the processing of the current task, rest of the code is **blocked**.

**Single-Threaded** in the sense that only one sequence of functions is loaded at a time. To me, both of these concepts sound a bit similar.

I'm aware of how callbacks, promises and async/await keywords help in dealing with asynchronous code. But what I don't understand is, how a block of code is *made* asynchronous. For example, this is a code from javascript.info:

```
 function loadScript(src) {
  // creates a <script> tag and append it to the page
  // this causes the script with given src to start loading and run when complete
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  document.head.append(script);
}
```

Now, when this function is called, it is supposed to be "asynchronous", in the sense that it won't block the subsequent lines of code from execution, but will carry on it's work "in the background".

```
loadScript('/my/script.js');
// the code below loadScript
// doesn't wait for the script loading to finish
// ...
```

What I don't understand is, what part of the function defined above made it asynchronous? The same goes for browser and API functione like `fetch()` and `addEventListener()`. *What* in their implementation made them asynchronous? How is task made to be performed **in the background without blocking the rest of the code**?

Comment: Just pass a callback function into it; there's still other ways.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Doesn't that have more to do with handling asynchronous code than *making* it asynchronous in the first place. My issue with the code above is, **why doesn't the call to loadScript() block the code immediately after the function call?**

Comment: As top said, define a callback but not call it immediately, pass it as argument to the listener or some async function.

Comment: Oh you mean how does the loadScript function not stop other function call?

Comment: @王仁宏 Like pass it as a callback to functions like setTimeOut() which would put it at the end of the Event Queue? I was under the impression that the function *itself*, is asynchronous because the loading of the script takes place in the background, without blocking subsequent code.

Comment: @王仁宏 Yes, exactly. I want to know why it isn't blocking subsequent code.

Comment: Yes they do. if you want to understand this, you need to know JavaScript runtime

Comment: "_what part of the function defined above made it asynchronous?_" - The answer to that question is simply this: "When the `.src` attribute gets set on the `<script>` tag". That starts the asyncronous process of preparing,downloading, and executing the script.

Comment: Additionally, tasks are not performed in the background - they are simply delayed until some future time. Eventually, when the`fetch()` completes or the event fires, the task (callback) associated with that async event gets placed directly onto the synchronous call stack.

Comment: https://blog.bitsrc.io/javascript-internals-javascript-engine-run-time-environment-settimeout-web-api-eeed263b1617?gi=1aca53d95348

async means just to wait for trigger

Comment: @RandyCasburn Does `fetch()` or 'scrip loading' in the example above use something like `setTimeOut()` to achieve this task of placing the associated callback at the end of the call stack? I was curious about how these are made asynchronous.

Comment: It depends on the mechanism. If some type of network request is involved, like with `fetch()`, then the inherit delay must be accommodated. So internally, network protocols provide their own "event" infrastructure to signal all sorts of async behavior. It does not use `setTimeout()` as that is a user facing API that we use to create async behavior, it its not used internally by the run time.

Answer (score 1):

> "What part of the function defined above made it asynchronous?"

The above function runs synchronously, but this calls for explanation. In general:

**Event Loop**

Browsers use an event loop to process "everything", including repainting the screen,
calling JavaScript code when timers expire, promises become settled, events have occurred and need to be fired on DOM elements, or in general calling JavaScript in response to an external event.

**Single Thread**

The event loop's task manager does not continue with other tasks after passing control to the JavaScript engine to execute JavaScript code. This is the "single threaded" part. JavaScript execution continues until it runs to completion, either by running to the end of top-level execution flow within a script element, or by returning from a call out from the event loop.

Single threading prevents JavaScript execution being interrupted by call outs from the event loop in a different thread with the ability to access the same program scope - which has the potential to  corrupt data and program state. Effectively single threading eliminates the need to implement a disable/enable interrupts system in JavaScript.

Note:  Multiple JavaScript threads can be created by setting up worker threads running in separate CPU threads. But communication between threads is tightly controlled and they do **not** share the same program scope.

**Blocking**

The cost of single threading is that execution of JavaScript in the main thread prevents the event loop task manager from proceeding with anything else. Hence executing JavaScript will block screen updating and responding to user input etc. until it returns to the event loop.

**Synchronous**

Synchronous code means code executed in a single call out from the event loop. Synchronous code execution flow proceeds through sequential, branch and looping constructs as you would read it in source code.

A synchronous API call is one that returns it result back to the caller with a `return` statement - without using a callback function or promise to supply the result.

**Asynchronous**

Asynchronous code is relative to something else: it is code that is not executed in the same call out from the event loop as some other execution context. E.G. a call back function passed to `setTimeout` is never called before the code that calls `setTimeout` returns to the event loop, so the call back is said to be called "asynchronously".

**`async` Functions**

Functions declared with the `async` keyword are a special case by design. Briefly

- the `await` operator returns to the event loop when executed. Hence code using the result of an `await` operator runs asynchronously with respect to code which executed the `await` operator (or prepared its operand).
- `async` functions always return a promise for the function's `return` value, not the returned value itself. Since promise values are not available synchronously, `async` function results can not be obtained synchronously in calling code.

---

### For parts of the question:

> What part of a function makes it asynchronous?

Standard functions are not inherently asynchronous: it is how they are called that determines their synchronicity or otherwise.  Describing a standard function as an "asynchronous function" would mean it is intended to be called asynchronously. Calling an `async` function an "asynchronous function" is a simplification: `async` functions are often called synchronously but always involve asynchronous code execution.

---

> API functione like fetch() and addEventListener()

```
 document.addEventListener("click", event=>console.log("clicked"))
```

adds the anonymous arrow function as a click event listener. Because the arrow function not called as part of the above script's execution flow, you can say it's called asynchronously when a user clicks the mouse.

Similar considerations apply to `fetch`: the code calling `fetch` returns to the event loop, the browser initiates a network request, waits for a response, places a task in a task queue and the event loop task manager calls the `fetch` callback with data. The callback runs asynchronously with respect to the code that called `fetch` in the first place.

---

> ```
> function loadScript(src) {
>   // creates a <script> tag and append it to the page
>   // this causes the script with given src to start loading and run when complete
>    let script = document.createElement('script');
>    script.src = src;
>    document.head.append(script);
>  }
> ```

A call to `loadScript` will execute the function's body code and synchronously return to the caller which continues execution after the call. It does however have side effects:

1. If `loadScript` is called while parsing HTML source, the absence of an `async` attribute on the script element means the HTML parser will stop parsing further HTML source until after the script has been fetched from the location specified in `src`, parsed by the JavaScript parser and executed. However execution of the loaded script is asynchronous: it only executes after the code calling `loadScript` returns to the event loop.
2. If the above code is executed after HTML parsing has reached end of input, the `async` attribute value is ignored and the script will be loaded asynchronously anyway. Placing "load" and "error" handlers on the script element allows obtaining notification of script load success or failure.